# keeping jquery ui accordions open on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to keep all the accordion tabs open on load? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gtUdH/) is a simple example I copied from jquery ui site. I am not sure how to implement that functionality.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071333/open-all-accordion-windows-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin call togglebox.  It will allow you to have all of the accordion tabs open at once, if that is what you are after.  Enjoy.

[Toggleboxes](http://michaelkeck.de/projects/jquery/)

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that this is a jQuery UI plugin and will look just like the jQuery UI Accordion, and uses the same style markup as the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the stock accordion control. According to the [jQuery UI documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) for the accordion:

> **NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion**
>
> An accordion doesn't allow more than one content panel to be open at the same time, and it takes a lot of effort to do that. If you are looking for a widget that allows more than one content panel to be open, don't use this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read the link you said, and in documentation they gave some jquery code. $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
  return false;
 }).next().hide();                                                        So can I implement the same with my existing divs?

Comment: Yes, I don't think its quite what you were looking for, but give it a try and see what you think...