# how to keep all accodins open by default in twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

How do you keep all the accodins open by default in twitter bootstrap 3?
By default they are closed and you have to click each tab for it to collapse. I don't want that. I want all the accordins to show its collapsed content, but at the same time give you the option to click the accordins again to un-collapse the content.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071333/open-all-accordion-windows-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `in` class to have them all open if you are manually coding each one. Example:

```
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

This will allow the items to close when you click them (and `in` will go away).

You can start with all tabs open like this with jQuery if you want a programmatic approach:

```
  <script>$('.collapse').collapse('show')</script>
```